# How can I split a data frame, apply some function, and put it back together?

Tags: r, dataframe, tidyverse

Often I have a data frame that contains a numerical variable and a categorical variable, and I want to split the numerical variable according to the categorical variable, perform some operation, and put it back together in the form of a data frame. The operation depends on the entire part of the numerical vector within a category, and will sometimes return a vector of a different length. I know how to do this in an ugly way (see 
example below), but it seems like a common operation so I'm wondering if there's a simpler way I'm not aware of. I would be especially interested to know if there is a solution using the `tidyverse`.

Here is an example of what I'm talking about.

```
df = data.frame(y=1:10, g=rep(c("a", "b"), each=5))
```

Say I want to standardize the variable `y` to be between 0 and 1 *for each level of the categorical variable*. Here is a general way to do it:

```
do.call(
    rbind,
    lapply(unique(df$g),
           function(level) {
               y.current = df$y[df$g==level]

               ## perform some operation
               y.new = (y.current-min(y.current))/
                   (max(y.current)-min(y.current))

               return(data.frame(y=y.new,
                                 g=level))
           }
           )
)
```

This requires a lot of typing and isn't very readable. Is there a better way?

Edit: Thanks for the great answers. The only thing I'm still interested in is a fully general method of doing this with the `tidyverse`. If we change the example to an operation where the size of the numerical vector is reduced but greater than one, the `group_by`/`mutate`/`summarize` combinations don't work. For example, say I want to remove the largest value within every group. I can do

```
library(dplyr)
df = data.frame(y=1:10, g=rep(c("a", "b"), each=5))
trans_df = df %>%
    group_by(g) %>%
    do(y=.$y[-which.max(.$y)])
```

The transformed data frame `trans_df` has the grouping variable with one observation per level, and the transformed variable as a list for each level of the grouping variable. I can put this in the original format using base R with

```
data.frame(g=rep(trans_df$g, times=sapply(trans_df$y, length)),
           y=do.call(c, trans_df$y))
```

but how can I do it using the `tidyverse`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using data.table:

```
library(data.table)
df=as.data.table(df)
df[,(y-min(y))/(max(y)-min(y)),by=g]
    g   V1
 1: a 0.00
 2: a 0.25
 3: a 0.50
 4: a 0.75
 5: a 1.00
 6: b 0.00
 7: b 0.25
 8: b 0.50
 9: b 0.75
10: b 1.00
```

Comment: and probably faster! =)

Comment: This is also the only approach that allows the transformed vectors to have different lengths out of the box. I'm sold!

Answer (score 0):

This is classic split-apply-combine methodology. You group by a categorical variable, apply some function to the individual groups, and combine back together. In `dplyr` this is handled by `group_by`.

```r
df <- data.frame(y=1:10, g=rep(c("a", "b"), each=5))

library(dplyr)
df %>%
  group_by(g) %>% 
  mutate(y2 = (y - min(y)) / (max(y) - min(y)))
#> # A tibble: 10 x 3
#> # Groups:   g [2]
#>        y g        y2
#>    <int> <fct> <dbl>
#>  1     1 a      0   
#>  2     2 a      0.25
#>  3     3 a      0.5 
#>  4     4 a      0.75
#>  5     5 a      1   
#>  6     6 b      0   
#>  7     7 b      0.25
#>  8     8 b      0.5 
#>  9     9 b      0.75
#> 10    10 b      1

df %>%
  group_by(g) %>% 
  top_n(-4, y)
#> # A tibble: 8 x 2
#> # Groups:   g [2]
#>       y g    
#>   <int> <fct>
#> 1     1 a    
#> 2     2 a    
#> 3     3 a    
#> 4     4 a    
#> 5     6 b    
#> 6     7 b    
#> 7     8 b    
#> 8     9 b
```

Created on 2018-07-03 by the [reprex package](http://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.2.0).

Comment: What if you need the operation to decrease the size? For example, what if you want to remove the largest value within each group? I tried `df %>% group_by(g) %>% transmute(y2=y[-which.max(y)])` and got an error.

Comment: `mutate` requires results to either be length one (in which case they are copied) or the same length, `summarise` requires length one. You can use `do` to carry out arbitrary computation, but in this case you just want to use `top_n`.

Comment: Okay, interesting. Let's stick with my example of removing the highest value for each group. I want to use `do` just to understand how it works. If I do `df %>% group_by(g) %>% do(y=y[-which.max(y)])` I get a data frame with one row for each level of the grouping variable and the transformed vector as lists. Is there a `tidyverse` way to turn this back into a data frame in the original format?

Comment: Yep, `tidyr::unnest` unless I mixed it up with something else from memory. `do` returns list-columns because it doesn't know what you are planning to return for each group, so it puts it in a list that can handle everything.

Answer (score 0):

In base R you could do this:

```
df$y <- ave(df$y,df$g, FUN = function(y) (y - min(y))/(max(y) - min(y)))
#       y g
# 1  0.00 a
# 2  0.25 a
# 3  0.50 a
# 4  0.75 a
# 5  1.00 a
# 6  0.00 b
# 7  0.25 b
# 8  0.50 b
# 9  0.75 b
# 10 1.00 b
```

Or this for the same effect:

```
split(df$y,df$g) <- tapply(df$y, df$g, function(y) (y - min(y))/(max(y) - min(y)))
```

A bit more flexible if you need to work in other variables of the data.frame:

```
by_ <- by(df, df$g, function(x) transform(x, y = (y - min(y))/(max(y) - min(y))))
do.call(rbind, by_)
#         y g
# a.1  0.00 a
# a.2  0.25 a
# a.3  0.50 a
# a.4  0.75 a
# a.5  1.00 a
# b.6  0.00 b
# b.7  0.25 b
# b.8  0.50 b
# b.9  0.75 b
# b.10 1.00 b
```